# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(a,b)=(b,0)$. Show that $Ker f = Im f$

Tags: linear-algebra

$Ker f = (a,0), a \in \mathbb{R}$. However b has to be zero so I get (0,0). Since $Im f = \mathbb{R}^2$ and (a,0) isn't all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ I don't see how the title is true?

Comment: You wrote $\ker f = \{(a, 0):\, a\in \mathbb{R}\}$; what is $b$?

Comment: @anomaly $b = 0$.

Comment: Why do you think that the image is all of $\mathbb R^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Ker f = (a,0), a \in \mathbb{R}, Im f = (b,0), b \in \mathbb{R}$ and they are both the X axis.